# Laravel 8 unable to get id from created model 'extended Pivot'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

have an issue
unable to get id from the created model. I check database row created normally

```
    $productStoreLink = ProductStoreLink::create([
      'product_id' => $item->id,
      'store_id' => $store['id'],
      'code' => $store['code']
]);
$productStoreLink->id;
```

In array `dd($productStoreLink)`

```
  "product_id" => 1
  "store_id" => "2"
  "code" => "5411183083684"
  "updated_at" => "2021-04-01T09:27:38.000000Z"
  "created_at" => "2021-04-01T09:27:38.000000Z"
```

I have mode. Yeah, this model has extends Pivot, but this is for more difficult operations.
QUESTION:
I wanna receive id from collection after creating a model. `$productStoreLink->id` in first codeblock.
Real to get id from this model?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ProductStoreLink extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'store_id',
        'product_id',
        'store_id',
        'code',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];
    public function price()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductStorePrices','product_store_link_id','id');
    }
    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductStorePrices','product_store_link_id','id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. What's your exact problem? What do you mean by "Real to get id from this model?"?

Comment: @NicoHaase I wanna receive id from collection after creating a model. `$productStoreLink->id` in first codeblock. now I receive null